# Exchanging control information in UnetStack

Tags: unetstack

Q1. We are designing new underwater routing protocol and implementing it in UnetStack. How nodes can exchange their control information to other nodes through beacon?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DatagramReq` with `to` field set to `0`, to share control information, using broadcast packets (beacons) to neighbouring nodes. See https://www.unetstack.net/javadoc/org/arl/unet/DatagramReq.html or https://www.unetstack.net/javadoc/index.html for more information on `DatagramReq`.